# Get list of categories in specific Outlook folder/inbox

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, outlook, mapi

I am trying to extract a list of categories in a specific Outlook folder with Python.

For example I am connected to the following inboxes "Personal" and "Work".

The following code will return the list of categories in the master list for my Personal inbox:

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
myfolder = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders["Work"]
for cat in myfolder.session.categories:
    print cat
```

So how do I get that list for my Work inbox?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#Outlook
outlook=win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").Stores

for i in range(outlook.count):
    for cat in outlook[i].categories:
        print(cat)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ SO has more of a preference for answers that have some text explaining why your code would be a good solution _ Quote from the section on 'How Do I Write A Good Answer': "_Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better._" _ Check out SO Help Center on 'Answering' for more guidelines >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering

Answer (score 0):

try iterating over the folder items.

```
myfolder = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders['Work']
for messages in myfolder.Items:
    print(messages)
```

Comment: You will get a list of regular messages. How does that help to retrieve a list of **categories**?

Comment: oh okay, so he doesn't want the list of messages instead, just the categories

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that works, it grabs categories and counts them over the last 7 days.

```html
mailbox = outlook.Folders.Item('aaaa@aaa.com')
inbox = mailbox.Folders.Item('Inbox')

today = datetime.datetime.today().date()
last_week = today - datetime.timedelta(days=7)

messages = inbox.Items.restrict(f'[ReceivedTime] >= "{last_week.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")}"')

categories = {}

for msg in messages:
    color = msg.Categories
    if color:
        separated_categories = color.split(',')
        for category in separated_categories:
            category = category.strip()
            if category in categories:
                categories[category] += 1
            else:
                categories[category] = 1
```